# Detect a change of iframe in page detail view in magnolia

Tags: magnolia

Is there a way to detect which node is being rendered when the user selects a link within the pages detail app and only the iframe changes? If just the the iframe is changing I need a mechanism that can call the parent page and send the path of the node that is being rendered in the iframe. We run Magnolia EE 5.6.11.
My issue is that I have a ValueChangeListener in a ComboBox that I use as a versionSelector in a PageBar extension in the pages detail app.

```
 // Create a selection component;
    private ComboBox versionSelector = new ComboBox();
    private Listener listener;
    private boolean isSettingValue;
    public VersionSelectorViewImpl(){
            construct();
    }

    private void construct() {
        versionSelector.setVisible(false);
        versionSelector.setSizeUndefined();
        versionSelector.setImmediate(true);
        versionSelector.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
        versionSelector.setTextInputAllowed(false);
        //setup listener for the selected item
        versionSelector.addValueChangeListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void valueChange(Property.ValueChangeEvent event) {
                  if (listener != null) {
                  listener.versionSelected((Object) event.getProperty().getValue());
                  }
              }
          });

    }
```

The implementation is similar to the LanguageSelector or VariantSelector. When someone activates a hyperlink in the page template the iframe changes and the valueChange method retrieves the wrong value (ie. the event is from the previous page).

When someone activates a link, the PagesEditorSubApp#updateNodePath calls the updateLocationDependentComponents which calls the PageBar.onLocationUpdate. This calls in our case the VersionSelector#setCurrentVersion method. At this point I would need to reload the page detail subapp so that the listener is correctly set to the new page. I tried using the pageEditorPresenter.refresh() method in the setCurrentVersion method but it didn't do it.

Comment: Where do you need to detect the change? In the template that is being rendered or in a (customized ?)  pages app or ...?

Comment: Hi @Jan I explained better in the main issue above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magnolia 5.x you need to fire `ContentChangeEvent` to trigger the refresh (and hope that subapp you want to refresh listens to it, which in case of page detail subapp shouldn't be a problem).
Or, since you mention `LanguageSelector`, you can indeed try to call `PageEditorPresenter` directly as it does from `info.magnolia.pages.app.editor.pagebar.languageselector.LanguageSelector#languageSelected`, tho unless you need to modify something in the presenter (eg. locale in the example above), it seems rather unnecessary coupling of the code.

Once you are migrating your code to Magnolia 6.x and new UI framework, you have more convenient way of triggering notification of datasource change which all the views consuming data from given source listen to and facilitating refresh that way (as is shown eg in `PasteComponentAction` [here](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/MODULES/repos/pages/browse/magnolia-pages-app/src/main/java/info/magnolia/pages/app/detail/action/PasteComponentsAction.java#74).